# C# httplistener error if remote ip

Tags: c#, webclient, httplistener

I created a httplistener and it works only with localhost as a prefix. It show an error if I change it to a remote server ip.

Here's the code:

```
 HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8080/");  // I need localhost replaced with remote ip
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            // Wait for a client request:
            HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();

            // Respond to the request:
            string msg = "You asked for: " + context.Request.RawUrl;
            context.Response.ContentLength64 = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(msg);
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;

            using (Stream s = context.Response.OutputStream)
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(s))
                writer.Write(msg);
        }
        listener.Stop();
```

THis is the web client:

```
   using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())        // Make a client request.
                    wc.DownloadString
                      ("http://"my public ip"(on  my router):8080/lg.txt"); //port forwarding is set
                MessageBox.Show("received");
```

It works only if I change "my public ip" to my local ip
Any ideas?

Comment: "remote server IP" - remote to who? It must be local to the server...

Comment: @Marc I meant my public IP address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your Windows Firewall on?  Try disabling it and see if that helps.  You may need to actually disable the Windows Firewall service (in your local services list).

Comment: Not that I know of ... I would think that would be a pretty big security vulnerability (if a program could add firewall rules - a malicious program could open up your computer to the world).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check the firewall. Perhaps more likely, though, is http.sys, which is used by HttpListener - you must make the prefix available to the account via "netsh". You can check this by running as an elevated admin account briefly - If it works it is probably a http.sys permissions issue.